# View document according to id

Tags: jsf, pdf, primefaces, resources

I have a Datatable that shows me some values from my DB. I added some buttons like edit, mail, etc. I'm trying to implement a button called "PDF" when i press, must show a modal window with the PDF previously generated by another button.

I tried with `<p:media />` and `<pe:documentViewer />` even to get the PDF directly on a xhtml like this:

```
<p:media value="C:\route\mypdf.pdf" />
```

To get the path and the name of the file, i have these lines on my Bean.

```
String exportDir = System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "/OrdenesRetiro/";
String nom_archivo = "Orden_de_Retiro" + or.getCod_ordenretiro() + ".pdf";
```

The `or.getCod_ordenretiro()` get the ID from my datatable and stores on a String value. I tried with document viewer extension and another forms, but really no clue, especially because i have to get the value of the datatable that stores on `or.getCod_ordenretiro()`

Any sugestion?

Comment: So it works if you have a text file instead of a pdf? The question as it stands not is not jsf or PrimeFaces related. Please improve the question (see [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). Otherwise you stand a change the question gets closed as being not clear

Comment: @Kukeltje I edited the post, i guess i did a bad explanation. I'm trying to implement a button to see the PDF according to the ID of the row, now success for now.

Comment: Explanation in basics was not to bad, it is a little better now, but still unclear since It still is not jsf, pdf or PrimeFaces related. You only have two plain java code lines...

Comment: @Kukeltje Yeah, i know. Cuz i tried with `<pe:documentviewer />` and `<p:media />` but no success.

Comment: Adding 'code snippets' does not make the question clearer or PrimeFaces or PFE related. And there are lots of Q/A on showing a pdf in jsf/primefaces. Get that as a basis and try to adapt to your usecase.